# Datatables doesn't populate when I do row.add().draw()

Tags: datatables

I have an app that I'm trying to migrate to using datatables. I'm stripping out as much of the underlying irrelevant code as I can here. Basically the app is one where a user makes a series of selections from dropdowns and based on those dropdowns it picks a json file, clears the table, runs through the elements in the json object, and adds rows to my table. At the end of all that it redraws.

To start off though I populate it with default data using th.e same operation. Either scenario produces the same result, but it somewhat explains why the initialization is in a separate IIFE

When I do that, I wind up with nothing. No js errors, no nothing. Just an empty datatable. Here's my relevant html code (I am simplifying it and obfuscating things, but nothing that should be relevant:

```
   <table id="conf">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="header">a</th>
        <th class="header">b</th>
        <th class="header">c</th>
        <th class="header">d</th>
        <th class="header">e</th>
        <th class="header">f</th>
        <th class="header">g</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
```

And the javascript

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var date="20190101"
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var table = $('#conf').DataTable({
      ordering:true,
      paging:false
    });
    ConfTable.PopulateTable(date);
  });
}());

var ConfTable = (function() {
  'use strict';    
  var table = $('#conf').DataTable();
  return{
     PopulateTable:function(){
      $.getJSON("data/conf/"+date+".json?_=" + new Date().getTime(),
      function(data, tableParam){
        table.clear().draw();
        GenerateTable(data)
        table.draw();
      });
    }
  }
  function GenerateTable(data) {
    for(var i=0; i<data.dockets.length; i++){
      addRow(data.dockets[i]);
    }
  }
  function addRow(thisCase) {
    table.row.add(
      [
        1,2,3,4,5,6,7
      ]
    );
  }
}());
```

I do intend to put actual data in the array eventually, but just to simplify for troubleshooting that is what I'm trying.  I have also tried adding it as an array of arrays using table.rows.add, and that array would look like this:

```
[
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
  ...
]
```

I have also attempted to put an object around the wrapper:

```
{"data": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]}
```

In all of these cases, the end result is an initialized datatable with the options I selected with no data in it, as if I had not performed the table.row.add operation. ("`No data available in table`") I've stepped through and confirmed that the code is being executed as intended, but I am stuck as to why I'm not getting any results back. If you need any additional information I'm happy to provide it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### PROBLEM

The problem with your code is in the order of code execution.
Your table gets initialized in the `ConfTable` before it gets initialized in the `ready` event handler.

You're using [function expressions](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/) (`(function(){}())`) which are executed in the order they are defined ( and before the document is ready). Therefore table fails to initialize in `ConfTable` and your `row.add()` method fails.

### SOLUTION

Either retrieve table instance inside each function or pass `table` variable as an argument.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  $(document).ready(function(){    
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      ordering:true,
      paging:false
    });
    ConfTable.PopulateTable();
  });
}());

var ConfTable = (function() {
  'use strict';      
  return{
     PopulateTable:function(){
        var table = $('#example').DataTable();
        table.clear().draw();
        GenerateTable({
            dockets: [[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
        });
        table.draw();
    }
  }
  function GenerateTable(data) {
    for(var i=0; i<data.dockets.length; i++){
      addRow(data.dockets[i]);
    }
  }
  function addRow(thisCase) {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    table.row.add(thisCase);
  }
}());
```

### EXAMPLE

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/zaLxwe4t/) for code and demonstration.